# How to transfer payment line into Sage 50?

Tags: c#, sage50

I'm using `sagecrmErp2008feeds` to the integration with my application. I'm able to create SalesCredit and SalesInvoice data. But I would like to transfer payment data from my application to Sage50.

**Which feed Entry should I use for that for payment transfer ?** Please see my Invoice code example. I would like to use the same way to transfer payment but I'm not getting feedentry for that. Here I'm using `salesInvoiceFeedEntry` feed entry.

```
public IResult<string> CreateSalesInvoice(Sage50Transaction data)
        {
            var result = new Result<string>();    
            try
            {
                var tradingAccount = GetCustomer(data.CustomerGuid);    
                if (tradingAccount == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Customer not found in Sage");
                }
                var salesInvoice = new salesInvoiceFeedEntry
                {
                    tradingAccount = tradingAccount
                };    
                salesInvoice.reference = data.ReferenceId;
                salesInvoice.reference2 = data.OurRef;
                salesInvoice.customerReference = data.YourRef;                    
                salesInvoice.netTotal = data.NetSub;
                salesInvoice.taxDate = data.TransactionDate;
                salesInvoice.date = data.TransactionDate;
                salesInvoice.salesInvoiceLines = new salesInvoiceLineFeed();    
                if (data.Lines != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in data.Lines)
                    {
                        salesInvoice.salesInvoiceLines.Entries.Add(GetInvoiceLineItem(item));
                    }
                }    
                var invoiceRequest = new SDataRequest(uri.Uri, salesInvoice, Sage.Integration.Messaging.Model.RequestVerb.POST);    
                invoiceRequest.Username = Username;
                invoiceRequest.Password = Password;    
                salesInvoiceFeedEntry savedSalesInvoice = new salesInvoiceFeedEntry();
                invoiceRequest.RequestFeedEntry<salesInvoiceFeedEntry>(savedSalesInvoice);    
                result.Data = savedSalesInvoice.UUID.ToString();                    
                result.HasData = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Data);    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.HasData = false;
                result.Data = null;
                result.Error = ex;
                result.FailMessage = ex.Message;
            }    
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, "payment transfer" is not possible from 3rd party to sage50, as the Sage 50 Accounts does not support this.